# Using differentials to approximate amount of copper in a tank

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

> Use differentials to find the approximate amount of copper in the
>   four sides and bottom of a rectangular copper tank that is $6$ feet
>   long, $4$ feet wide and $3$ feet deep inside, if the sheet-copper is
>   $\dfrac14$ inch thick.

I know that $v(x,y,z)=xyz$, and $$\mathrm{d}v=Vx\,\mathrm{d}x + Vy\,\mathrm{d}y +Vz\,\mathrm{d}z$$ which is equal to $yz\,\mathrm{d}x + xz\,\mathrm{d}y + xy\,\mathrm{d}z$.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to think of the $1/4$ inch sheet as a thin one.  In that case you can multiply the total area of the five sides of the tank by the thickness to get the volume.  This is not exact because the copper in the corners is either counted twice if the dimensions are outside or not at all if the dimensions are inside, but in this context it is the square of a small quantity and considered negligible.

Comment: I am curious as to how would differentials play a role in this method?

Comment: @an4s  The volume is $A \Delta t$ where $A$ is the area and $\Delta t$ is the small thickness of the copper sheet.

Comment: @RossMillikan Could an alternative method be to find dx,dy, and dz, and plug it in to the dv equation and you get 9/4 by doing this. What answer are you getting by doing your method?

Comment: Sure.  You have to notice that $dx=dy=\frac 12$ inch while $dz=\frac 14$ inch because you have two of each vertical face and only one horizontal face.  You also need to notice that the units of thickness are inches while the dimensions of the box are feet, so need to make a conversion here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach this by treating the tank as two separate boxes with different lengths ($l$), widths ($w$), and depths ($d$):

Box $1$: $l\times w\times d=6\times 4\times 3$ (find volume $V_1$ by integration)

Box $2$: $(l-0.5)\times (w-0.5)\times (3-0.25)=(6-0.5)\times (4-0.5)\times (3-0.25)$ (find volume $V_2$ by integration)

Thus, copper in the tank: $V=V_1-V_2$

Comment: This is not what the problem requests.  It is correct (assuming the dimensions you are given are outside, not inside), but not the approximation requested.